# Author disambiguation problem with suffix

Tags: biblatex, apa-style

I am having a problem with name disambiguation that is puzzling me. When disambiguating names biblatex is using suffix initials, rather than the complete name suffix. What I am seeing is:

> T. A. Parker I., S. A. Parker, et al. 1982
>   T. A. Parker I., Schulenberg, G. R. Graves, et al. 1985
>   T. A. Parker I., Schulenberg, Kessler, et al. 1995
>   T. A. Parker I., Stotz, et al. 1996
>   Gottdenker et al. 2005

What I expect to see is:

> T. A. Parker III, S. A. Parker, et al. 1982
>   T. A. Parker III, Schulenberg, Graves, et al. 1985
>   T. A. Parker III, Schulenberg, Kessler, et al. 1995
>   T. A. Parker III, Stotz, et al. 1996
>   Gottdenker et al. 2005

My truncated bib file:

```
% Encoding: UTF-8

@Article{parkerschulenbergetal1985avifauna,
    author       = {Parker, III, T. A. and Schulenberg, T. S. and Graves, G. R. and Braun, M. J.},
    title        = {The avifauna of the Huancabamba region, northern Peru},
    journaltitle = {Ornithological Monographs},
    year         = {1985},
    issuetitle   = {Neotropical ornithology (P. A. Buckley, M. S. Foster, E. S. Morton, R. S. Ridgley, and F. G. Buckley, (Eds.))},
    volume       = {36,},
    pages        = {169--197},
    doi          = {10.2307/40168282},
    keywords     = {validated},
}

@Article{parkerschulenbergetal1995natural,
    author       = {Parker, III, T. A. and Schulenberg, T. S. and Kessler, M. and Wust, W. H.},
    title        = {Natural history and conservation of the endemic avifauna in north-west Peru},
    journaltitle = {Bird Conservation International},
    year         = {1995},
    issuetitle   = {In memory of Ted Parker},
    volume       = {5},
    number       = {2-3},
    pages        = {201--232},
    doi          = {10.1017/S0959270900001015},
    keywords     = {validated},
}

@InBook{parkerstotzetal1996ecological,
    author   = {Parker, III, T. A. and Stotz, D. F. and Fitzpatrick, J. W.},
    title    = {Ecological and distributional databases},
    pages    = {113--436},
    crossref = {stotzfitzpatricketal1996neotropical},
    keywords = {validated, new},
}

@Book{stotzfitzpatricketal1996neotropical,
    author     = {Stotz, D. F. and Fitzpatrick, J. W. and Parker, III, T. A. and Moskovits, D. K.},
    title      = {Neotropical birds: ecology and conservation},
    year       = {1996},
    publisher  = {University of Chicago Press},
    location   = {Chicago},
    keywords   = {validated},
}

@Article{gottdenkerwalshetal2005assessing,
    author       = {Gottdenker, N. L. and Walsh, T. and Vargas, H. and Merkel, J. and Jiménez, G. U. and Miller, R. E. and Dailey, M. and Parker, P. G.},
    title        = {Assessing the risks of introduced chickens and their pathogens to native birds in the Galápagos Archipelago},
    journaltitle = {Biological Conservation},
    year         = {2005},
    volume       = {126},
    number       = {3},
    pages        = {429--439},
    doi          = {10.1016/j.biocon.2005.06.025},
    keywords     = {validated},
}

@Book{parkerparkeretal1982annotated,
    author    = {Parker, III, T. A. and Parker, S. A. and Plenge, M. A.},
    title     = {An annotated checklist of Peruvian birds},
    year      = {1982},
    publisher = {Buteo Books},
    location  = {Vermillion, SD},
    keywords  = {validated, new},
}
```

These are five examples with the three different Parkers in my bibliography of 2500+ entries. I am seeing the same results from names which have a "Jr." suffix that have to be disambiguated as well. Parker, S.A. causes disambiguation. Parker, P.G. does not, and I am not sure why.

My minimum working example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[letterpaper, margin=.75in]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{1EF3}{\`y}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{03B2}{$\beta$}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{0301}{FIXME!!!!}
\usepackage[default]{sourcesanspro}
\usepackage[    
    style=authoryear-comp,
    sortcites=false,
    backend=biber,
    sorting=nyt,
    block=space,
    hyperref=auto,
    bibstyle=apa,
    maxnames=125,
    maxcitenames=2,
    mincitenames=1,
    apamaxprtauth=125,
    apabackref=true,
    uniquename=true
    ]{biblatex}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\DeclareFieldFormat{apacase}{#1}
\addbibresource{MWE.bib} 
\raggedright
\begin{document}
\cite{parkerparkeretal1982annotated}\\
\cite{parkerschulenbergetal1985avifauna}\\
\cite{parkerschulenbergetal1995natural}\\
\cite{parkerstotzetal1996ecological}\\
\cite{gottdenkerwalshetal2005assessing}\\
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

How can I get the APA name disambiguation to use the entire suffix, rather than just the suffix initial?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A word of warning: Your preamble uses `style=authoryear-comp,` and then `bibstyle=apa,` this means that your citations do not use APA style. Hence I simplified the example.

With the code below we always print the full name suffix instead of an abbreviation of the suffix that might come out wrong.

We only had to modify the `labeldate` name format to always print the full `suffix` even if the first name is printed with initials only.

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[    
  style=authoryear-comp,
]{biblatex}

\DeclareNameFormat{labelname}{%
  \ifcase\value{uniquename}%
    \usebibmacro{name:family}
      {\namepartfamily}
      {\namepartgiven}
      {\namepartprefix}
      {\namepartsuffix}%
  \or
    \ifuseprefix
      {\usebibmacro{name:given-family}
        {\namepartfamily}
        {\namepartgiveni}
        {\namepartprefix}
        {\namepartsuffix}}
      {\usebibmacro{name:given-family}
        {\namepartfamily}
        {\namepartgiveni}
        {\namepartprefixi}
        {\namepartsuffix}}%
  \or
    \usebibmacro{name:given-family}
      {\namepartfamily}
      {\namepartgiven}
      {\namepartprefix}
      {\namepartsuffix}%
  \fi
  \usebibmacro{name:andothers}}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@Article{parkerschulenbergetal1985avifauna,
    author       = {Parker, III, T. A. and Schulenberg, T. S. and Graves, G. R. and Braun, M. J.},
    title        = {The avifauna of the Huancabamba region, northern Peru},
    journaltitle = {Ornithological Monographs},
    year         = {1985},
    issuetitle   = {Neotropical ornithology (P. A. Buckley, M. S. Foster, E. S. Morton, R. S. Ridgley, and F. G. Buckley, (Eds.))},
    volume       = {36,},
    pages        = {169--197},
    doi          = {10.2307/40168282},
    keywords     = {validated},
}

@Article{parkerschulenbergetal1995natural,
    author       = {Parker, III, T. A. and Schulenberg, T. S. and Kessler, M. and Wust, W. H.},
    title        = {Natural history and conservation of the endemic avifauna in north-west Peru},
    journaltitle = {Bird Conservation International},
    year         = {1995},
    issuetitle   = {In memory of Ted Parker},
    volume       = {5},
    number       = {2-3},
    pages        = {201--232},
    doi          = {10.1017/S0959270900001015},
    keywords     = {validated},
}

@InBook{parkerstotzetal1996ecological,
    author   = {Parker, III, T. A. and Stotz, D. F. and Fitzpatrick, J. W.},
    title    = {Ecological and distributional databases},
    pages    = {113--436},
    crossref = {stotzfitzpatricketal1996neotropical},
    keywords = {validated, new},
}

@Book{stotzfitzpatricketal1996neotropical,
    author     = {Stotz, D. F. and Fitzpatrick, J. W. and Parker, III, T. A. and Moskovits, D. K.},
    title      = {Neotropical birds: ecology and conservation},
    year       = {1996},
    publisher  = {University of Chicago Press},
    location   = {Chicago},
    keywords   = {validated},
}

@Article{gottdenkerwalshetal2005assessing,
    author       = {Gottdenker, N. L. and Walsh, T. and Vargas, H. and Merkel, J. and Jiménez, G. U. and Miller, R. E. and Dailey, M. and Parker, P. G.},
    title        = {Assessing the risks of introduced chickens and their pathogens to native birds in the Galápagos Archipelago},
    journaltitle = {Biological Conservation},
    year         = {2005},
    volume       = {126},
    number       = {3},
    pages        = {429--439},
    doi          = {10.1016/j.biocon.2005.06.025},
    keywords     = {validated},
}

@Book{parkerparkeretal1982annotated,
    author    = {Parker, III, T. A. and Parker, S. A. and Plenge, M. A.},
    title     = {An annotated checklist of Peruvian birds},
    year      = {1982},
    publisher = {Buteo Books},
    location  = {Vermillion, SD},
    keywords  = {validated, new},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}


\begin{document}
\cite{parkerparkeretal1982annotated}\\
\cite{parkerschulenbergetal1985avifauna}\\
\cite{parkerschulenbergetal1995natural}\\
\cite{parkerstotzetal1996ecological}\\
\cite{gottdenkerwalshetal2005assessing}\\
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

> T. A. Parker III, S. A. Parker and Plenge 1982
>
> T. A. Parker III, Schulenberg, Graves et al. 1985
>
> T. A. Parker III, Schulenberg, Kessler et al. 1995
>
> T. A. Parker III, Stotz and Fitzpatrick 1996
>
> Gottdenker et al. 2005

P. G. Parker in `gottdenkerwalshetal2005assessing` alone does not trigger the Parker `uniquename` feature because that name is never shown in citations (the chance that disambiguation is needed is thus small). The default setting `uniquename=full` only disambiguates up to `maxnames`, if you want to disambiguate across all names even if they might not be seen, you need `uniquename=allfull`.

Comment: Thanks. You have exactly answered my questions, and solved my problem. As an aside, I am intentionally using different citation and bib styles.